# Is there a centralised subscription system for new and forthcoming economic books?

Tags: reference-request, books

Many publishers (e.g. MIT Press, Oxford University Press, Harvard Press, Norton, *et cetera*) are constantly releasing new economic books. I could subscribe to email alerts for each of them (for example, [MIT](http://mit.us2.list-manage2.com/subscribe?u=7caff40e82d72e9429c33df2a&id=4f766e83e7), [OUP](https://global.oup.com/academic/emailpreferences/signin/?cc=cy&lang=en), [Harvard](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/news/mailing-list.html)). However, this has two problems:

1. I will get a lot of emails.
2. Unless I subscribe to all/most, I will be missing from many other, lesser known, perhaps heterodox publishers.

I wonder whether there is a single, centralised system which can alert me, say, every month, of the plethora of new economic books published or forthcoming.

I know [Inomics](https://inomics.com) is a good centralised system for conferences and jobs alert, but I am not aware of book alerts. [RePEc](http://repec.org/) does not seem to provide that service either.

Comment: You could go to a big book selling website. Amazon has a new book category, not sure about other sites. I doubt that Amazon would send alerts, but you could set yourself a reminder to check it out each month. Otherwise, you could try searching for periodicals aimed at librarians; that's exactly the sort of resource they use. I doubt that such information would be free.

Comment: I would also like to know this actually. Same for journals. I receive many TOCs in separate emails but I'd like to receive one email each month with all journals in a few topic areas including working papers and an abstract + link.

Comment: @toby for working papers I use http://nep.repec.org/ Very handy, weekly email.

Comment: @luchonacho, thanks I use the same. I wish though that I would receive fewer emails and more bundled together: e.g. once a month all the topics that I am subscribed to in one email. I don't know if this is possible?